# Clip path problem in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm working in Illustrator CS4, and when I save from EPS to SVG I get these messages:

- Foreign artworks are expanded (I see this error when I save to SVG)
- clipping will be lost on roundtrip (And I see this one when I open the SVG I saved)

This SVG opens fine in illustrator, but some of its parts disappear in Firefox.

What does this clip path mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's the artwork made of? Blends? Gradients? Raster elements? Glows? Shadows?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you use clipping masks. Try to cutoff all clipping masks and all heavy effects.